# Simulating H-bridge in LTSpice

Tags: pwm, ltspice, simulation, h-bridge

I'm creating an H-bridge to control a torque motor (TM-60).
For this, I'm using an H-bridge consisting of 4 N-channel MOSFETS (FCP165N65S3) and the gate-driver LTC4446. I'm using LTSPice to simulate.

This is what I've sat up so far:

[image: LTSpice schematic]

However, I got stuck when I had to set up the PWMs. The MCU used is NXP S32K146, and I want to switch at 20 kHz.
I guess my questions are:

1. What PWM do I need to test if my circuit works?
2. Do I need a different PWM for the high-side vs. the low-side?
3. What kind of measurement is relevant to look at?
4. Anything else I should consider?

Comment: To me it looks like you don't know much about the underlying theory. If this it the case then I would suggest reading more about it before diving into such topics. Otherwise you're likely to keep on stumbling on unknown things and keep on asking for help at every step -- that can be quite demotivating. But if I misunderstood then please ignore this comment, and I wish you good luck.

Answer (score 1):

1. The same frequency you want to use in your application. i.e. 20 kHz
2. They need to operate on the same frequency. Furthermore they have to be synced and have to be inverted. Otherwise you will ruin the bridge. (Details can be far more complicated) In fact, as you have opted to use a driver IC all those measures are already taken by the driver ICs designers
3. difficult. A lot. You have to monitor gate-source voltages for unpredicted jumps, the boost capacitor for keeping its voltage and so on.
4. a lot. But we won't know, where to start, because we can't guess what you already know.

related to 2.: It might be that you were talking about different frequencies for the two half bridges when you mentioned high-side and low-side. In that case, of course, that is possible, but has consequences. Some desired, some not. We do that, but calculations aren't easy and it makes sense in conjunction with complicated filter networks only.

Why are U5 and U6 drawn upside down? The right halfbridge probably won't do what you expect when source is connected to a higher level than drain and gate.